Do I need Apache Spark to execute my Airflow DAG tasks?
I have a workflow with multiple DAGs. Every DAG has multiple tasks.
These tasks are simple ETL tasks. It involves geo data in the form of kmls, csvs.
An example task:
We have meta data of road collection points in the form of latitude, longitude. We make linestrings of these collections, break the linestrings at road intersections, filter out duplicate linestrings by applying different approaches. Example, if one linestring occurs in a 8 feet buffer of another, one has to be deleted.
The data is mostly csv. Each csv roughly 20mb in size. Do I need Apache Spark to make my processes distributed?
Airflow can also work on data in distributed fashion. Currently, we are using local executor but we can use celery executor to make our processes distributed.

Celery and spark are both used for distributed computing. However, Spark is WAY more suitable for data processing jobs (larger volumes, in-memory processing, fault tolerance, convenient APIs). You would ideally use celery to schedule asynchronous tasks with smaller workloads - sending emails, background jobs, generating reports, etc. You would use spark when you want to crunch a lot of data.
In your case using celery will you help you trigger your tasks in a distributed fashion. But the actual execution of each task depends on the underlying processing engine (spark, pandas, etc).
Three scenarios

Ony celery - Design each task to be a straightforward python job (pandas ideally) and let celery do the task queue management
Only spark - Assuming you have multiple dags and tasks solely for the purpose of distributed computing, you could replace all of it with a single (or handful of) spark job(s)
Celery AND Spark - This is a situation where you use celery for managing the tasks and each task in itself is a spark job

Use 1 when the data processed by each task is low-moderate volume but the processing logics for tasks are vastly different.
Use 2 when the total volume of data is large but all tasks are more or less similar in terms of processing logic
Use 3 when the volume of data in each task is large AND you have additional background activities like (sending notifications, generating reports, updating dashboards, etc) with every task
Hope this helps!
